# Rate-limiting to prevent extrinsic spamming

Tags: extrinsic, security, spam

Is there any rate-limiting defense system in Substrate, that would prevent an attacker with sufficient funds to spam extrinsics on a given parachain ?

Is there any maximum amount of extrinsics per block that an account can invoke ?